# jQuery combining 2 bind functions (TypeError: a is undefined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

Please give me a piece of advice.

I'm trying to write a function from 2 similar functions by combining its common parts. 
From these 2 functions, I'd like to get "selected1" & "selected2", and use these value in the next function, calc.

```
var selected;
var selected1;
var selected2;

$( '.type1' ).bind('change', function () {
    var values = [];
    $( 'input.type1:checkbox:checked' ).each(function ( _, el ) {
        values.push( base64decode( $( el ).data( 'val' ) ) );
        if ( values.length > 1 ) {
            values[0] = $.map(values[0], function (val, i) {
                return values[0][i] | values[1][i];
            });
            values.splice(1,1);
        }
    });
    selected1 = result;
    calc();
});

$( '.type2' ).bind('change', function () {
    var values = [];
    $( 'input.type2:checkbox:checked' ).each(function ( _, el ) {
        values.push( base64decode( $( el ).data( 'val' ) ) );
        if ( values.length > 1 ) {
            values[0] = $.map(values[0], function (val, i) {
                return values[0][i] | values[1][i];
            });
            values.splice(1,1);
        }
    });
    selected2 = result;
    calc();
});

function calc () {
    var selected3 = $.map(selected1, function (val, i) {
        return selected1[i] & selected2[i];
    });
    selected = base64encode( selected3 );
    overlays();
};
```

When I write as above, both selected1&2 are defined as global variables, so function calc works.
However, it doesn't work on my rewrite code. The firebug says "TypeError: a is undefined".
Here is my code:

```
function tab (checkedTab, selected) {
    var values = [];
    checkedTab.each(function ( _, el ) {
        values.push( base64decode ($( el ).data( 'val' ) ) );
        if ( values.length > 1 ) {
            values[0] = $.map(values[0], function (val, i) {
                return values[0][i] | values[1][i];
            });
            values.splice(1,1);
        }
    });
    selected = values[0];
};
$( '.type1' ).bind('change', function () {
    tab ($( 'input.type1:checkbox:checked' ), 'selected1');
    calc();
});
$( '.type2' ).bind('change', function () {
    tab ($( 'input.type2:checkbox:checked' ), 'selected2');
    calc();
});
```

Could someone please tell me why my code doesn't work?

Comment: `selected3` is array. does `base64encode()` take array as input? also `"TypeError: a is undefined"` its because you pass undefined as argument (or wrong other type). you should debug variables you pass to jquery functions step-by-step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your comments, Peter. 
After debugging variables, it finally works! 
This may not be the best way, but I will post my rewrite code as reference.

```
var values;

function tab (checkedTab) {
    values = [];
        checkedTab.each(function ( _, el ) {
        values.push( base64decode ($( el ).data( 'val' ) ) );
        if ( values.length > 1 ) {
            values[0] = $.map(values[0], function (val, i) {
                return values[0][i] | values[1][i];
            });
            values.splice(1,1);
        }
    });
    return values[0];
};
$( '.type1' ).bind('change', function () {
    selected1 = tab ($( 'input.type1:checkbox:checked' ));
    calc();
});
$( '.type2' ).bind('change', function () {
    selected2 = tab ($( 'input.type2:checkbox:checked' ));
    calc();
});
```